# jQuery HTML table with radio buttons to CSV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, csv

So, I've found plenty of posts regarding exporting a basic HTML table to CSV using jQuery, but that's not all I'm needing to happen.

I need a table that will have a list of names coming from a database, and in the same row as each name I will need a yes or no radio button essentially. I tried doing this already, but it won't export the yes or no, just the names.

This was the example I was using & I edited it below to test the radio button: http://jsfiddle.net/terryyounghk/kpegu/

```
<table>
        <tbody><tr>
            <th>Column One</th>
            <th>Column Two</th>
            <th>Column Three</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>row1 Col1</td>
            <td><input type="radio" value="yes" name="yes"></td>
            <td>row1 Col3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>row2 Col1</td>
            <td>row2 Col2</td>
            <td>row2 Col3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>row3 Col1</td>
            <td>row3 Col2</td>
            <td>row3 Col3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>row4 'Col1'</td>
            <td>row4 'Col2'</td>
            <td>row4 'Col3'</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>row5 "Col1"</td>
            <td>row5 "Col2"</td>
            <td>row5 "Col3"</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>row6 "Col1"</td>
            <td>row6 "Col2"</td>
            <td>row6 "Col3"</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table>
```

Comment: so, you want the button to appear in the actual csv is that what you're saying?

Comment: The only option I have as of right now, is to make this a form that will submit to a new page with the results in a table with no other form elements, and export the csv from that page. It's not ideal, but if I find nothing else, it'll suffice.

Comment: @Pamblam no, sorry I wasn't clear. I want the RESULT to show up in the csv. So if I tick "yes", I'd like yes to be what appears in that column.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KPEGU/4421/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var $col = $(col),
    $radio = $col.find('input[type=radio]'),
    text = $col.text();

if ($radio.length > 0) {
    return $radio.val();
}
```

make determine statement on handling table cell data. I changed a little your code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nrexs8bp/)

Comment: After further testing, it looks like 'yes' is coming up regardless of what I select or if I even select it at all.

Comment: @CodyRobinson you need to modify the code a little bit. using checkbox replacing radio, and not return the checkbox value directly, but return value according to weather it checked